# Pyparsing delimited list only returns first element

Tags: python, pyparsing

Here is my code :

```
l = "1.3E-2   2.5E+1"
parser = Word(alphanums + '+-.')
grammar = delimitedList(parser,delim='\t ')
print(grammar.parseString(l))
```

It returns :

```
['1.3E-2']
```

Obiously, I want all both values, not a single one, any idea what is going on ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Works if you switch to raw strings:

```
l = r"1.3E-2\t2.5E+1"
parser = Word(alphanums + '+-.')
grammar = delimitedList(parser, delim=r'\t')
print(grammar.parseString(l))
```

Prints:

```
['1.3E-2', '2.5E+1']
```

In general, delimitedList works with something like `PDPDP` where `P` is the parse target and `D` is the delimter or delimiting sequence.

You have `delim='\t '`. That specifically is a delimiter of 1 tab followed by 1 space; it is not either tab or space.

Answer (score 8):

As @dawg explains, delimitedList is intended for cases where you have an expression with separating *non-whitespace* delimiters, typically commas.  Pyparsing implicitly skips over whitespace, so in the pyparsing world, what you are really seeing is not a delimitedList, but `OneOrMore(realnumber)`. Also, parseString internally calls `str.expandtabs` on the provided input string, unless you use the `parseWithTabs=True` argument. Expanding tabs to spaces helps preserve columnar alignment of data when it is in tabular form, and when I originally wrote pyparsing, this was a prevalent use case.

If you have control over this data, then you might want to use a different delimiter than `<TAB>`, perhaps commas or semicolons. If you are stuck with this format, but determined to use pyparsing, then use OneOrMore.

As you move forward, you will also want to be more precise about the expressions you define and the variable names that you use. The name "parser" is not very informative, and the pattern of `Word(alphanums+'+-.')` will match a lot of things besides valid real values in scientific notation. I understand if you are just trying to get *anything* working, this is a reasonable first cut, and you can come back and tune it once you get something going.  If in fact you are going to be parsing real numbers, here is an expression that might be useful:

```
realnum = Regex(r'[+-]?\d+\.\d*([eE][+-]?\d+)?').setParseAction(lambda t: float(t[0]))
```

Then you can define your grammar as "OneOrMore(realnum)", which is also a lot more self-explanatory. And the parse action will convert your strings to floats at parse time, which will save you step later when actually working with the parsed values.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Paul for this answer, especially the detailed explanation. I will move to OneOrMore (it's actually the first thing I tried but this raw string mistake made me look to delimitedList). I am using this regex already, same thing about variable names, I just wrote a quick and dirty example for the sake of simplicity.